# Django two same signal types

Tags: django

I don't understand how 2 signals executed together relate to each other. For example consider the following:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'  

    # Overriding save method-image resizing
    def save(self, **kwargs):
        super().save(kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)  # save() of parent class

#Signals when a user is registered his profile is automatically updated
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile(user=instance)  #could do Profile.objects.create(user=instance) instead to replace the 2 lines
        instance.profile.save() #reverse query
```

I understand the following:

create_profile: is my receiver function. It will do something when .save() method takes place, in our case will create a Profile instance and save it.

sender: is the Model that is actually signalling this to take place. So in our case, if we want a signal to take place when the save method is executed on User model then the sender would be the User.

post_save is the signal

Regarding my question now. I have seen the above function broken down into the two following functions.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save() #reverse query
```

I am aware it is pointless since I could do what I did but I don't understand how does my save_profile function 'remembers' the Profile instance made on create_profile?

As far as I can tell, save_profile is a separate function that has no reference to create_profile function (example by create_profile or so on the save_profile body).

I am assuming when a user instance is saved the create_profile function is executed it makes a profile object then the save_profile function is executed and for same user instance the profile object is saved,
but I still don't understand how it knows I refer to same profile made by that instance.

Comment: Actually, the signals are ***not executing simultaneously, but sequentially***

Answer (score 0):

Why you not state it is example from Corey tutorial ?

Corey Tutorial, part 8, and if I not mistaken he didnt have to create two separate signals, because one was enough ..

To your question:
The functions are:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile_handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
   #Run each time a new user is created, and attach to the user a profile !
   #    sender - The model class (User)
   #    instance - The actual instance being saved. (User)
   #    created - A boolean. 'True' if a new record was created.

   if created:
       Profile.objects.create(user=instance) 
       #'create' - initialize and save a profile and attach it to the User



# Now, lets save the profile each time the user object is been saved.
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
   instance.profile.save() # User.profile.save() - saves the profile
```

we know from the Django [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#creating-objects), that create() method include save() operation in it.

So not only that the second signal is redundant (because we can do its operations in the first signal), further more - the save is a bit redundant it self (because create calls save).